# Usage of Numpy's maximum method

Tags: numpy, matrix

I am unable to understand why the following code does not work. It is my understanding that the "maximum" method in Numpy returns an array with the element-wise maximum of any number of arrays in the argument.

```
import numpy as np
frame1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
frame2 = np.array([[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [9, 9, 9]])
frame3 = np.array([[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [10, 10, 10]])
result1 = np.maximum(frame2, frame3)
print(result1)
result2 = np.maximum(frame1, frame2, frame3)
print(result2)
```

The results are:

```
[[ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [10 10 10]]
[[2 3 4]
 [5 6 7]
 [9 9 9]]
```

Is there something really trivial that I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: From the docs, `np.maximum` interprets `frame3` as output array. So, it writes the maximum of `frame1` and `frame2` to `frame3`.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use `np.stack((frame1,frame2,frame3), -1).max(-1)`.

Comment: From the docs: `Compare two arrays`, not `any number`.